# how i can make svnlook tree view just 2 level?

Tags: linux, svn, command-line, solaris

**how i can make `svnlook tree` view just 2 level ?**

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? Do you need to list out folders with depth of 2? If so, you can use svn ls with a for loop to help with this.

Comment: i use `svn list svn+ssh://` but the problem in this command it is require password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only limit on a single level via -N option but not for two levels.

Comment: please you can give me example ?

Comment: or where i can put it .... `svnlook tree -N` if yes ...the following appear ... svnlook: invalid option character: N

Comment: You need to mention the version of subversion client you are using. Looks like you are using an older version that does not allow for the option "-N"